# Ionic icons conflicting names

Tags: ionic-framework, icons

Im building a mobile application with Ionic 3.9, i faced an issue using the ionic icons.

when i used the icon **square-outline** it displays another icon  **compass-outline**  as follows:

[image]

This is the code in html:

```
<ion-icon name="square-outline"></ion-icon>
```

> This issue is only in IOS, it works fine in Android.